# How to check if a docker instance is running?

Tags: python, macos, docker

I am using Python to start docker instances.

How can I identify if they are running? I can pretty easily use `docker ps` from terminal like:

```
docker ps | grep myimagename
```

and if this returns anything, the image is running. If it returns an empty string, the image is not running.

However, I cannot understand how to get `subprocess.Popen` to work with this - it requires a list of *arguments* so something like:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'ps', '|', 'grep', 'myimagename'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print p.stdout
```

does not work because it tries to take the "docker ps" and make it "docker" and "ps" commands (which docker doesn't support).

It doesn't seem I can give it the full command, either, as `Popen` tries to run the *entire* first argument as the executable, so this fails:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen('docker ps | grep myimagename', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print p.stdout
```

Is there a way to actually run `docker ps` from Python? I don't know if trying to use `subprocess` is the best route or not. It is what I am using to run the docker containers, however, so it seemed to be the right path.

- How can I determine if a docker instance is running from a Python script?

Comment: You don't need the `| grep` part, you can do that from `python`. Otherwise, does the `shell = True` argument to `Popen()` help? [See here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: @slezica sort of. I guess using another example there I can use a try/except block around`subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)` and get it to work - that feels... so hacky so I'd like to think there is a better way (when no matches are found that apparently returns a non-0 code, so check_output throws an exception).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use  `subprocess.check_output` setting `shell=True` (thanks slezica!):

```
s = subprocess.check_output('docker ps', shell=True)
print 'Results of docker ps' + s
```

if the `docker ps` command fails (for example you don't start your docker-machine) then `check_output` will throw an exception.

A simple find can then verify your container is found / not-found:

```
if s.find('containername') != -1:
    print 'found!'
else:
    print 'not found.'
```

I would recommend using the container hash id and not container *name* in this case, too, as the name may be duplicated in the image name or other results of the `docker ps`.

Comment: I am getting bewlo error on executing 
s = subprocess.check_output('docker ps', shell=True)


subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'docker ps' returned non-zero exit status 1

Answer (score 10):

You can use the python docker client:

```
import docker
DOCKER_CLIENT = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
RUNNING = 'running'

def is_running(container_name):
    """
    verify the status of a sniffer container by it's name
    :param container_name: the name of the container
    :return: Boolean if the status is ok
    """
    container = DOCKER_CLIENT.containers.get(container_name)

    container_state = container.attrs['State']

    container_is_running = container_state['Status'] == RUNNING

    return container_is_running

my_container_name = "asdf"
print(is_running(my_container_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it seems like you are on your way, I would recommend you use [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) as it accesses the socket created by docker to issue API request.  I use this library currently use this library and it is real time saver.