# What is docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' e2c657561363 equivalent in docker-py?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

What is docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' e2c657561363 equivalent in docker-py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into python bindings for the docker api: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#container-objects.

See this too: [How to check if a docker instance is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586900/how-to-check-if-a-docker-instance-is-running) (I would not recommend it since it's a lot lower-level than the above).

Comment: Is it possible to get the result without using dockerpy library

Comment: Yes, make system calls with subprocess.

Comment: Suppose container id is 'cd65a218a4' then I need to check whether it is up or not

Comment: @EdwardArrow edited my answer. If you found it helpful, please don't forget to upvote/hit the green tick so that others know what to look for

Comment: Could you please help me to get the details of particular container when container ID is passed. I tried client.containers.get(container.id) but it is showing only <Container: 6888be2555>

Comment: Need to get further details such like active or not

Comment: @EdwardArrow https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.status Don't forget to upvote

Comment: Went through the doc.But I couldn't find the required command

Comment: How to check mounts of container is up ?

Comment: how to check whether the space utilization is proper in servers using python (need to automate using docker-py)